# How to disable sorting on Group Column description field in Data grid?

Tags: c#, sorting, xaml, uwp, syncfusion

I have a data grid in my xaml code. I am applying Sorting by handing Sort column changed event in my view model. There is a separate Group column description field also for that.

When I am sorting the grid by a column, the debugger shows me correct results depending on whatever the order i am selecting but it is getting sorted again by the grouped column when it appears on the screen.

This is my xaml code:

```
xmlns:my="using:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
<my:SfDataGrid 
                    x:Name="ListReportForFilter" 
                    Margin="20,20,20,0"
                    GroupCaptionTextFormat="Tracking Number: {Key}" 
                    AutoExpandGroups="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding SearchReportPageFullList,Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Visibility="Visible"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    AllowFiltering="True"
                    AllowSorting="True"
                    ColumnSizer="Star" 
                    SelectionMode="None">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="FilterChanged">
                            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FilterChangedOnGrid}" />
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SortColumnsChanged">
                            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SortingChangedOnGrid}" />
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <my:SfDataGrid.GroupColumnDescriptions>
                        <my:GroupColumnDescription ColumnName="TrackingNumber"/>
                    </my:SfDataGrid.GroupColumnDescriptions>
                    <my:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                        <my:GridTextColumn  HeaderText="Recipient"
                                        TextAlignment="Center"
                                MappingName="Recipient"
                                            AllowBlankFilters="False"
                                 />
                        <my:GridTextColumn  HeaderText="Function"
                                MappingName="Function"
                                            AllowBlankFilters="False"
                                            TextAlignment="Center"
                                 />
                        <my:GridTextColumn  HeaderText="Carrier"
                                MappingName="Carrier"
                                            AllowBlankFilters="False"
                                            TextAlignment="Center"
                                 />
                        <my:GridTextColumn HeaderText="Tracking Number"
                                MappingName="TrackingNumber"
                                            IsHidden="True"
                                            TextAlignment="Center"
                                />
                        <my:GridTextColumn  HeaderText="Item Type"
                                MappingName="ItemType"
                                            AllowBlankFilters="False"
                                            TextAlignment="Center"
                                 />
                        <my:GridTextColumn  HeaderText="Date"
                                MappingName="Date"
                                            AllowBlankFilters="False"
                                            TextAlignment="Center"
                                 />
                        <my:GridTextColumn  HeaderText="Location"
                                MappingName="Location"
                                            AllowBlankFilters="False"
                                            TextAlignment="Center"
                                />
                        <my:GridTextColumn  HeaderText="Duration (hrs)"
                                MappingName="Duration"
                                            AllowBlankFilters="False"
                                            TextAlignment="Center"
                                />
                    </my:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                </my:SfDataGrid>
```

This is my view model code with Sort Columns Changed event:

```
public DelegateCommand<GridSortColumnsChangedEventArgs> SortingChangedOnGrid { get; }
SortingChangedOnGrid = new DelegateCommand<GridSortColumnsChangedEventArgs(SortingOnSFDataGridChanged);

private void SortingOnSFDataGridChanged(GridSortColumnsChangedEventArgs sortingdata)
    {
        try
        {
            var newSearchtotalFullList = new List<UndeliveredReportModel>();
            var columnNameSelected = sortingdata.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault().ColumnName;

            List<UndeliveredReportModel> totalDataAsPerFilterr = new List<UndeliveredReportModel>();
            switch (columnNameSelected)
            {
                case "Recipient":
                    if (sortingdata.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault().SortDirection == Syncfusion.Data.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderBy(x => x.Recipient).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Recipient).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                case "Function":
                    if (sortingdata.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault().SortDirection == Syncfusion.Data.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderBy(x => x.Function).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Function).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                case "ItemType":
                    if (sortingdata.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault().SortDirection == Syncfusion.Data.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderBy(x => x.ItemType).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderByDescending(x => x.ItemType).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                case "Carrier":
                    if (sortingdata.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault().SortDirection == Syncfusion.Data.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderBy(x => x.Carrier).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Carrier).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                case "Date":
                    if (sortingdata.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault().SortDirection == Syncfusion.Data.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                case "Location":
                    if (sortingdata.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault().SortDirection == Syncfusion.Data.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderBy(x => x.Location).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Location).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                case "TrackingNumber":
                    if (sortingdata.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault().SortDirection == Syncfusion.Data.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderBy(x => x.TrackingNumber).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderByDescending(x => x.TrackingNumber).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                case "Duration":
                    if (sortingdata.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault().SortDirection == Syncfusion.Data.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        //var asc = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderBy(x=>x.Duration).GroupBy(y => y.TrackingNumber).ToList();
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderBy(x => x.Duration).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //var asc = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Duration).GroupBy(y => y.TrackingNumber).OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
                        totalDataAsPerFilterr = SearchReportPageFullList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Duration).ToList();
                        newSearchtotalFullList = newSearchtotalFullList.Concat(totalDataAsPerFilterr).ToList();
                        break;
                    }
            }
SearchReportPageFullList = newSearchtotalFullList;
 }
catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
}
```

I am using Syncfusion UWP tool for this feature because it was meeting our requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your requirement can be achieved by setting the SortGroupRecords value as False in GroupColumnDescriptions in SfDataGrid. Please refer the below code snippet for your reference,

```
<syncfusion:SfDataGrid.GroupColumnDescriptions>
   <syncfusion:GroupColumnDescription ColumnName="OrderID" SortGroupRecords="False" /> 
</syncfusion:SfDataGrid.GroupColumnDescriptions>
```